# passing parameter to a function in a select statement dynamically

Tags: oracle

how to use dynamic value while passing the parameter in select statement.

I have a function like below ....

```
create or replace function get_old_GSL (p_vendor_site_id in varchar2) return varchar2
is
  v_sup_gsl VARCHAR2(30);
  v_ret_val VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTR(ATTRIBUTE52,1,6)
    INTO v_sup_gsl 
    FROM gecm_dff_ext 
    WHERE primary_table ='AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL'
      AND   primary_key = p_vendor_site_id
      and   attribute52 is not null;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     v_sup_gsl := NULL;
  END;
  BEGIN
    IF v_sup_gsl IS NOT NULL THEN
       SELECT segment1
       INTO v_ret_val
       FROM ap_suppliers
       WHERE segment1 = v_sup_gsl;  
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  v_ret_val := NULL;
END;        
return(v_ret_val);
END;
```

Testing the function:

```
---------------------
--> select GET_OLD_GSL(22758460) as xyz from dual;
--> select GET_OLD_GSL(22758529) as xyz from dual;
--> select GET_OLD_GSL(22760317) as xyz from dual;
--> select GET_OLD_GSL(22758389) as xyz from dual;
--> select GET_OLD_GSL(22759519) as xyz from dual;
```

Here, iam using column '`vendor_site_id`' of '`ap_supplier_sites_all`' table .

My requirement is passing this parameter dynamically without hard coding the parameter each time i pass.

Comment: I want like . select GET_OLD_GSL(--dynamic parameter--) from dual;

Comment: Instead of dual, use `select GET_OLD_GSL(vendor_site_id) FROM ap_supplier_sites_all`

Comment: "Pass a variable" (instead of hardcoding a specific value) does not mean "dynamic parameter." In SQL context, you have "dynamic" <something> only when table or column names are not known in advance. In your case, you want to pass in a variable (a column value in this case); there is nothing "dynamic" about your situation.

Comment: it's a nice habit to define a variable with `type`s such as `ap_suppliers.segment1%type` for `v_ret_val` instead of `varchar2(30)`

Comment: if i want to add this function in to a package and call the function through a select statement within the package like below                               select get_old_gsl(a.vendor_site_id) as VendorNumber from ap_supplier_sites_all a,gecm_dff_ext b 
where b.primary_key = a.vendor_site_id 
and b.attribute52 is not null ;

Comment: I don't want to get the null values ....

Comment: select get_old_gsl(a.vendor_site_id) as VendorNumber from ap_supplier_sites_all a,gecm_dff_ext b 
where b.primary_key = a.vendor_site_id 
and b.attribute52 is not null 
and a.vendor_site_id is not null